# How to open a popup with sending POST variable using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, post

How can I open a PHP popup with post data to it?

I have done this using GET:

```
<a href='javascript: function(var1);'>click to open</a>

function(var1){
    url = "/Test/Popup.php?var="+var1;
    params  = 'width='+screen.width;
    params += ', height='+screen.height;
    params += ', top=0, left=0'
    params += ', fullscreen=yes';
    mapWindow = window.open(url,'myMapWindow', params);
}
```

I need to do this using POST.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

The `window.open()` function doesn't allow for `POST` requests. The only alternative would be to use an Ajax call to retrieve the content and then open the popup. You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and more specifically [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to load the content and in the callback do this:

```
$.post('/Test/Popup.php', {'var': var1}, function(data) {
  var params = 'width='+screen.width;
  params += ', height='+screen.height;
  params += ', top=0, left=0'
  params += ', fullscreen=yes';

  var mapWindow = window.open('', 'myMapWindow', params); 
  mapWindow.document.write(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but the problem here is this code is opening a blank window...
Where are we giving url to window.open...?

Comment: @Raviraja - You're not actually giving it a URL. This uses jQuery's `.post` function to load the content first. The `mapWindow.document.write(data);` adds the body of the result into the popup window.

Comment: @Raviraja - For a working example, see [http://jsfiddle.net/4Tfk7/](http://jsfiddle.net/4Tfk7/).

Comment: @Raviraja - You won't be able to do a POST request that way. You need to use something to make the request first and open the popup. The easiest way is using jQuery as in my example above. Again, look at the jsfiddle.net link above for a fully working example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that via window.open. That will always result in a GET request. It is not possible to get window.open to perform a POST.

You work around it by using an AJAX call to do the post, then have the response handler pop up a window and fill in the response text.

Alternatively, you can dynamically build a form with a `method="post"`, and a `target="newwindow"`. It won't valiate as proper HTML anymore, but with the target you can force the form's submission response to go into another window.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
    if(window.ActiveXObject) {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    return alert ("Your browser does not support ajax! Some features may not be working.. Please upgrade your browser.");
}
var url = "/Test/Popup.php";
var params = "var="+var1;
var http = GetXmlHttpObject();
http.open("POST", url, true);    
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        var mapWindow = window.open('', 'myMapWindow', params); 
            mapWindow.document.write(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

ajax POST method is a way to send POST requests via javascript combining it with a window can be tricky.. [src](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php)

you can use `mapWindow.document.write(http.responseText);` to add the response text to the window. (credit for window write code goes to @Francois Deschenes)

Comment: Please keep in mind that `XMLHttpRequest()` is **not** cross-browser compatible.